# Azure - Mapping a virtual directory to file service share in cloud service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-files

Reference to : [Mapping an Azure File Service CloudFileShare as a virtual directory on each instance of a cloud service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960184/mapping-an-azure-file-service-cloudfileshare-as-a-virtual-directory-on-each-inst)

**I encounter an issue when I am trying to create a virtual directory in Azure Cloud Service, and the virtual directory is mapped to Azure file service.**

What I have done

1) use `<Runtime executionContext="elevated" />` for webrole in in ServiceDefinition.csdef

2) in WebRole.cs
    I mount the drive (as described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/27/persisting-connections-to-microsoft-azure-files.aspx for PaaS) I also do it in application start.

```
    public static void MountShare(string shareName,
                          string driveLetterAndColon,
                          string username,
                          string password)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(driveLetterAndColon))
        {
            // Make sure we aren't using this driveLetter for another mapping
            WNetCancelConnection2(driveLetterAndColon, 0, true);
        }

        NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE();
        nr.dwType = ResourceType.RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
        nr.lpRemoteName = shareName;
        nr.lpLocalName = driveLetterAndColon;

        int result = WNetAddConnection2(nr, password, username, 0);

            if (result != 0 || result != 85)
//85 indicates the drive name is already used. in this scenario, it means the drive is already mapped.
        {
            throw new Exception("WNetAddConnection2 failed with error " + result);
        }
    }
```

3) In WebRole.cs, I create the virtual directories by the following,

```
app.VirtualDirectories.Add("/asset/cms", @"s:\cms");
```

4) In WebRole.cs, I use the following to make the AppPool run in the admin account I created for remote desktop,

```
applicationPool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.SpecificUser;
applicationPool.ProcessModel.UserName = appPoolUser;
applicationPool.ProcessModel.Password = appPoolPass;
applicationPool.ProcessModel.LoadUserProfile = true;
```

**Problem:**

I am unable to get anything from /asset/cms. **It comes back with 500.19** if I try to access the files inside, and it says '**The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.**', and specifically it points to s:\cms\web.config which does not exist. When I remote to the cloud service instance, and open IIS mgr, I can see the virtual directories are created correctly.

I guess it's a permission problem. But I am not able to edit permission of the virtual directory since it's mapped to a network drive.

How can I solve this problem? -- Now the above problem is solved and the cloud service can access the file service share. But, new problem - is it possible to use the network_service identity to run the AppPool?

Comment: Can you give an update on this?

Comment: @KeremDemirer 
I did not work on this further. 

We just intended to use it in web app instead but Azure File Service does not support web app and will not either. 
MS has declined the request. Below for your reference.


https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/6084609-allow-map-azure-file-share-microsoft-azure-file-s